# itext pdf repeated rows when setHeaderRows

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, tabular

I using itexpdf to generate a large table, when I set setHeaderRows, the first rows displayed in a page are repeat in the next page. 
I.e. in the following code

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(605, 784), 28, 28, 42, 28);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/temp/tabla.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(5);
tabla.setComplete(false);
tabla.setWidthPercentage(100);
tabla.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
tabla.setHeaderRows(5);
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    celda = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph encabezado = new Paragraph("Header "+i);      
    celda.addElement(encabezado);
    celda.setGrayFill(0.8f);
    tabla.addCell(celda);
}              

for(int k=0; k<300; k++)
{
    celda = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph contenido = new Paragraph("Cell "+k, helvetica11);
    celda.addElement(contenido);                    
    tabla.addCell(celda);
}

tabla.completeRow(); 
document.add(tabla);
document.close();
```

To run shown a table in two pages, has the same header but the first four rows are repeated on both pages.

I should do so that  don't repeat any row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see `tabla.setHeaderRows(5);` I expect the first **five** rows to be repeated. That is: the first row with the 5 header cells and the first 4 rows of data.

Are you sure you didn't mean to write `tabla.setHeaderRows(1);`?

Comment: happened that the additional header information needed for group classification and not set colspan in the cell container of header by this reason not show table in some cases.

Comment: My requirement is not to repeat heading for PdfPTable on all pages. Even if I comment this line, it still repeats. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If I don't set header rows, no rows are repeated.